# How to set root log level for application in micronaut

Tags: micronaut

I am working on a cli application that can take in some options: `--info`, `--debug`, `--trace`. I would like to use the arguments to set the logging level for the entire application. Is there an easy way to do this? This is what I have tried so far:

```
    LogLevel level;
    if(info) {
      level = LogLevel.INFO;
    } else if (debug) {
      level = LogLevel.DEBUG;
    } else if (trace) {
      level = LogLevel.TRACE;
    } else {
      level = LogLevel.WARN;
    }
    loggingSystem.setLogLevel(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME, level);
```

`loggingSystem` is injected into the class.

```
  @Inject
  private LoggingSystem loggingSystem;
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not quite sure if I get your point. Here is what I found in the official documentation.

[Controlling Log Levels with Properties](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#propertySource)

```
Controlling Log Levels with Properties

Log levels can be configured via properties defined in application.yml (and environment variables) with the log.level prefix:

logger:
    levels:
        foo.bar: ERROR
```

Note that the ability to control log levels via config is controlled via the LoggingSystem interface. Currently Micronaut ships with a single implementation that allows setting log levels for the Logback library. If another library is chosen you should provide a bean that implements this interface.

Comment: This is a command line application so I would like to use an argument to control the logging level instead of an environment variable or config file. This is similar to what gradle does with `--debug` for instance.

Comment: better link - https://docs.micronaut.io/3.5.3/guide/index.html#loggingConfiguration - the link is pointing to the wrong place in the doc and SO queue reviewers do not like improving SO content ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to do the work:

```
 public String setLogLevel(String loggerName, Level level) {
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    Logger logger = loggerName.equalsIgnoreCase("root") ?
            loggerContext.getLogger(loggerName) : loggerContext.exists(loggerName);
    if (logger != null) {
        logger.setLevel(level);
        return loggerName + " to level : " + level;
    } else {
        return "Logger Not Found";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are asking just to find a more handy way of doing so, because your example (from question) is working.

You can try something like

```java
    @Inject
    LoggingSystem loggingSystem;

    @Option(names = {"-l", "--log"}, defaultValue = "INFO", description = "Log level, available: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR")
    String logLevel;


    public void run() {
       loggingSystem.setLogLevel(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME,  LogLevel.valueOf(logLevel));

    }
```